# Static IPv4 & IPv6 configuration on CentOS 6.2

Tags: centos, networking, ipv6, ipv4

I try to configure static IPv4 & IPv6 configuration on CentOS 6.2.

The configuration below works perfectly :

```
# ifconfig eth0 x.x.x.x/29
# route add defalt gw x.x.x.y

# ip addr add dev eth0 XXXX:C810:3001:D00::3/56
# ip -6 route add default XXXX:C810:3001:D00::1
```

However, I want to keep this configuration after a reboot.

So I made the following configuration:

Enabling IPv6

```
[root@test network-scripts]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=test.net
NETWORKING_IPV6=yes
```

Interface Configuration

```
[root@test network-scripts]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="static"
ONBOOT="yes"
HWADDR="2C:C3:AC:A8:C3:3E"
IPADDR=x.x.x.x
GATEWAY=x.x.x.x
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
TYPE=Ethernet
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6ADDR=XXXX:C810:3001:D00::3/56
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=XXXX:C810:3001:D00::1

DNS1=208.67.222.222
DNS2=208.67.220.220
# Only DNS{1,2} according to /usr/share/doc/initscripts-9.03.27/sysconfig.txt
# DNS3=2620:0:ccc::2
# DNS4=2620:0:ccD::2
```

Restarting the Network

```
[root@test network-scripts]# service network restart
Arrêt de l'interface eth0 :  État du périphérique&nbsp;: 3 (déconnecté)
                                                           [  OK  ]
Arrêt de l'interface loopback :                            [  OK  ]
Activation de l'interface loopback :                       [  OK  ]
Activation de l'interface eth0 :  État de connexion active&nbsp;: activation
État de chemin actif&nbsp;: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3
état&nbsp;: activé
Connexion activée
                                                           [  OK  ]
```

[root@test network-scripts]# cat /var/log/message

```
Mar 13 14:32:13 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> (eth0): device state change: 8 -> 3 (reason 39)
Mar 13 14:32:13 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason: 39).
Mar 13 14:32:13 test avahi-daemon[8311]: Withdrawing address record for x.x.x.x on eth0.
Mar 13 14:32:13 test avahi-daemon[8311]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address x.x.x.x.
Mar 13 14:32:13 test avahi-daemon[8311]: Interface eth0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Mar 13 14:32:14 test kernel: lo: Disabled Privacy Extensions
Mar 13 14:32:14 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> Activation (eth0) starting connection 'System eth0'
Mar 13 14:32:14 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> (eth0): device state change: 3 -> 4 (reason 0)
Mar 13 14:32:14 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Mar 13 14:32:14 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Mar 13 14:32:14 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Mar 13 14:32:14 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Mar 13 14:32:14 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Mar 13 14:32:14 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> (eth0): device state change: 4 -> 5 (reason 0)
Mar 13 14:32:14 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
Mar 13 14:32:14 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Mar 13 14:32:14 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Mar 13 14:32:14 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Mar 13 14:32:14 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> (eth0): device state change: 5 -> 7 (reason 0)
Mar 13 14:32:14 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IP4 Configure Get) scheduled...
Mar 13 14:32:14 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
Mar 13 14:32:14 test avahi-daemon[8311]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::1ec1:deff:feb8:a2fd on eth0.
Mar 13 14:32:14 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Mar 13 14:32:14 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IP4 Configure Get) started...
Mar 13 14:32:14 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IP4 Configure Get) complete.
Mar 13 14:32:15 test avahi-daemon[8311]: Registering new address record for fe80::1ec1:deff:feb8:a2fd on eth0.*.
Mar 13 14:32:35 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> (eth0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Mar 13 14:32:35 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IP6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Mar 13 14:32:35 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IP6 Configure Timeout) started...
Mar 13 14:32:35 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) scheduled...
Mar 13 14:32:35 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IP6 Configure Timeout) complete.
Mar 13 14:32:35 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) started...
Mar 13 14:32:35 test avahi-daemon[8311]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address x.x.x.x.
Mar 13 14:32:35 test avahi-daemon[8311]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Mar 13 14:32:35 test avahi-daemon[8311]: Registering new address record for x.x.x.x on eth0.IPv4.
Mar 13 14:32:36 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> (eth0): device state change: 7 -> 8 (reason 0)
Mar 13 14:32:36 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> Policy set 'System eth0' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Mar 13 14:32:36 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> Activation (eth0) successful, device activated.
Mar 13 14:32:36 test NetworkManager[8299]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) complete.
```

IPv6 configuration is not working ...

```
[root@test network-scripts]# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:c1:de:b8:a3:fd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet x.x.x.x/29 brd x.x.x.x scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::1ec1:deff:feb8:a3fd/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

IPv6 addresses of the resolvers are not even in the resolv.conf !

**Did I miss a configuration step ?**

I thought that the IPv6 configuration would be a formality ..

```
[root@test network-scripts]# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID:    CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.2 (Final)
Release:    6.2
Codename:    Final
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Network Manager is trying to override your static configuration settings. As root or sudo user, run:

```
service NetworkManager stop
```

If you don't have service, try:

```
/etc/init.d/NetworkManager stop
```

Also, you can set the static interfaces to not be managed by the NetworkManager, which is what I did in my CentOS configs merely by adding the line

```
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

to your static config files. Your static configuration files don't have that line, meaning the NetworkManager will try to control those interfaces instead of ignoring them.

See [here for reference](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/disable-networkmanager-598907/) on disabling and/or uninstalling NM.

Comment: Thanks ! 
We must also disable the service NetowrkManager start with the command `ntsysv`. Otherwise the /etc/resolv.conf is reformatted at startup.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this network-manager conflicting with static network configuration files? Disable network-manager if you run CentOS on server, NM is silly and there's no need to have "dynamically" changing network settings.